# Aliased property is undefined in Route

Tags: ember.js

**Meta Qustion**

I have a route that returns a list of dynamic names. In a child route, I'd like to generate an error if the url's parameter specifies a name not in the parent's dynamic list. What is the best way to do this?

**More Information**

Within a custom Route's model method, I am trying to access a property (via getProperties) that is an alias to a parent controller property. Unfortunately, the value is always undefined. I have verified that I can access standard properties (not aliases) just fine. Are aliases available in the Router's model method?

**JSBin**

I have slightly modified the "colors" ember example to give an idea of what I am trying to do.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hocusiqano/5/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'needs' doesn't work on routes, it only works on controllers.  Aliases work, but with needs not doing anything on the route, it's just aliasing an undefined property.

Additionally, `index` in your example isn't a parent resource to colors, it's at the same level.

`application` route would be considered a parent resource, and you could fetch that from the `colors` route using `var colors = this.modelFor('application');` and you'd have to change your `IndexRoute` to `ApplicationRoute`